# How to drop the unwanted columns after resampling a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, resampling

I have created a dataframe with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
Timestamp = pd.date_range('21/1/2019', periods=2500, freq='10S')
df = pd.DataFrame(dtype=float)
df['Timestamp'] = Timestamp
LTP = np.arange(100,2600,1)
lowest_sell = np.arange(121,1371,0.5)
highest_buy = np.arange(131,1381,0.5)
df['a-LTP'] = LTP
df['b-Lowest_Sell'] = lowest_sell
df['c-Highest_Buy'] = highest_buy
```

This is how dataframe looks like:

[image]

I resampled it with the following command:

```
resamp = df.set_index('Timestamp').resample('1T').ohlc()
```

This is how resampled dataframe looks like:

[image]

If you notice, the name of columns is changed in the resampled dataframe.
I am only want 'close' price columns after resampling.
This is the list of the columns:
[image]

How do I delete the unwanted columns? since the column names are complex now, I am not able to use simple column drop method.

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
close_columns = [column for column in resamp.columns if column[1] == 'close']

result = resamp[close_columns]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
                    a-LTP b-Lowest_Sell c-Highest_Buy
                    close         close         close
Timestamp                                            
2019-01-21 00:00:00   105         123.5         133.5
2019-01-21 00:01:00   111         126.5         136.5
2019-01-21 00:02:00   117         129.5         139.5
2019-01-21 00:03:00   123         132.5         142.5
2019-01-21 00:04:00   129         135.5         145.5
...                   ...           ...           ...
2019-01-21 06:52:00  2577        1359.5        1369.5
2019-01-21 06:53:00  2583        1362.5        1372.5
2019-01-21 06:54:00  2589        1365.5        1375.5
2019-01-21 06:55:00  2595        1368.5        1378.5
2019-01-21 06:56:00  2599        1370.5        1380.5

[417 rows x 3 columns]
```

To rename you could do:

```
lookup = {'a-LTP': 'resampled_LTP', 'b-Lowest_Sell': 'resampled_lowest_sell', 'c-Highest_Buy': 'resampled_highest_buy'}
result.columns = [lookup.get(column[0]) for column in result.columns]
print(result.columns)
```

**Output**

```
Index(['resampled_LTP', 'resampled_lowest_sell', 'resampled_highest_buy'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: it looks very neat.  column names are still (a-LTP, close), (b-Lowest_Sell), (c-Highest_Buy). How do I access them in code? How can I rename them?

Comment: Yes you can rename them as usual, what would you want the output to be?

Comment: say: resampled_LTP, resampled_lowest_sell, resampled_highest_buy

Comment: @KawaiKx - check last solution of @molybdenum42 - `resamp.columns = resamp.columns.droplevel(-1)`

Answer (score 2):

You now have a MultiIndex. These are still columns, just a bit more roundabout to deal with. I recommend something like this:

```py
idx = pd.IndexSlice
resamp = resamp.loc[:,idx[:,"close"]]
```

Alternatively, without the IndexSlice class you can get the same result, but the syntax is messier:

```py
resamp = resamp.loc[:,(slice(None),"close")]
```

**Output:**

```
>> resamp.head()
                    a-LTP b-Lowest_Sell c-Highest_Buy
                    close         close         close
Timestamp
2019-01-21 00:00:00   105         123.5         133.5
2019-01-21 00:01:00   111         126.5         136.5
2019-01-21 00:02:00   117         129.5         139.5
2019-01-21 00:03:00   123         132.5         142.5
2019-01-21 00:04:00   129         135.5         145.5
```

You'll still have a MultiIndex (with only one unique second-level entry) after all this - to get rid of the second level, you can do this:

```py
resamp.columns = resamp.columns.droplevel(-1)
```

Comment: got the following error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'

Answer (score 2):

If want select column `close` in `MultiIndex` simpliest is use [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
df = df.xs('close', axis=1, level=1)
```

---

You can flatten columns names if want avoid `MultiIndex`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
```

Comment: perfect just what I needed! how would you apply a conditional with the map? for e.g `lambda x : x if ' ' not in x` i have a multi index with some blanks that I want the map to ignore. If hard to explain i can open new question

Comment: I tried running it. It generated error. AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'get_loc_level'